# Three.js JSON loader on apache

Tags: json, apache, three.js

I have created a 3D model website for showing JSON files with three.js.

This is working if I open the html file locally stored on my computer.
But if I upload all files to my webserver (apache2) nothing is displayed.

I have tried to run a simple Three.js example without JSON loader and this is working on my webserver.

I also checked the paths to the JSON files and they are all relative paths I can open each file in the browser if I type the name or if I use firebug I can browse all files.

I checked the apache error log but no error message appears.

What can be the problem or how can I find out what the problem is?

This is my Script part.

```
        var scene;
        var camera;
        var controls;
        var geometryArray;

        initializeScene();

        animateScene();

        function initializeScene(){
            if(!Detector.webgl){
                Detector.addGetWebGLMessage();
                return;
            }

            renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias:true});
            renderer.setClearColor(0x000000, 1);

            canvasWidth = window.innerWidth;
            canvasHeight = window.innerHeight;

            renderer.setSize(canvasWidth, canvasHeight);

            document.getElementById("WebGLCanvas").appendChild(renderer.domElement);

            scene = new THREE.Scene();

            camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(45, canvasWidth / canvasHeight, 1, 100);
            camera.position.set(0, 0, 6);
            camera.lookAt(scene.position);
            scene.add(camera);

            controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);

            axisSystem = new AxisSystem(camera, controls);

            geometryArray = new Object();
            var loader = new THREE.JSONLoader();
            for(var i = 0; i < jsonFileNames.length; i++){
                var layerName = jsonFileNames[i].split("/")[2].split(".")[0];
                loader.load(layerName, jsonFileNames[i], function(geometry, materials, layerName){
                    mesh = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({vertexColors: THREE.FaceColors, side:THREE.DoubleSide}));
                    mesh.scale.set(0.013, 0.013, 0.013);
                    scene.add(mesh);
                    geometryArray[layerName] = mesh;
                }, layerName);
            }

            var directionalLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(0xffffff, 1.0);
            directionalLight.position = camera.position;
            scene.add(directionalLight);
        }

        function animateScene(){
            controls.update();
            axisSystem.animate();
            requestAnimationFrame(animateScene);
            renderScene();
        }

        function renderScene(){
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            axisSystem.render();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that your files are not being loaded because of the **for** loop you are using. Load is asynchronous, so each time you call **loader.load**, you corrupt object state from previous call. Try creating new loader in every step or come up with different way of loading multiple files.